Combine raster information to vector layer
I have a line vector layer and 2 raster layers; slope and dem. For each feature in the line vector layer, I would like to get the slope and dem information generated into its attribute table. Is there a tool that does this in QGIS?

A single line can cross multiple raster pixels. How would you want represent to this in its attribute table record?

How do you want to use this data afterwards ? Do you want lists of points at each of the line vertices, with the related raster data. Or do you want the Line object itself to hold the information for each of it's vertices. Both can be done, but which one to choose depends on what you want to do.

@Kasper I want the line object.

@user2856 I want the line vector layer to have 2 fields in its attribute table that will have the slope and dem information for each.

You can use the Drape function in the Processing Toolbox to map the Z (altitude) and M (use it for slope) within you line data.
First Drape to set Z value from raster (use the DEM as raster source).
This will add a Z value to each of the vertices in your line

Now take the resulting line and Set the M value from raster(use the Slope as a raster source)
Your lines now contain both information on each vertex
If you need more resolution, you can Densifythe initial lines before to make sure they have more vertices
Z and M information can then be accessed as Z and M properties of any vertex.
Vertices can be accessed as point_n($geometry,index)
Z and M values are z(point_n($geometry,index)) and  m(point_n($geometry,index))
For instance, if you want to label vertices with Z and M values, do the following (see this answer for details and use the formula from below)
concat('A:',round(z(point_n( $geometry,@geometry_point_num))),'\n','S:',round(m(point_n( $geometry,@geometry_point_num))))

Altitude and Slope have been sampled and are displayed as Labels on each vertex.


Additional notes:
One limitation here is that the Z & M values are within the geometry information, they are not fields in the attribute table (there is only one attribute table line for each line object)
You can easily extract all vertices from the lines once the my have the Z & M properties, with the Processing Toolbox:Extract vertices)
Then add columns using Field calculatorand create a Z and M entry (or Altitude / Slope) by setting them to (z(geometry) and m(geometry))
Alternatively, depending on what you exactly need, you could even Extract vertices first, and then Drape the Z & M values directly on the point vertices.
With that you should be able to do pretty much anything


The Drape function does not create a field that shows the slope or dem information for each feature in the line vector layer?

Please be very specific about what you want to do with the data, how you want it to be formatted. There are so many possible options here, you need to provide details otherwise this answer cannot be focused on solving your need.

I managed to do it and achieved my goal. Thank you very much for your time.

Thanks, please flag your question as resolved
